# Should i use a single or double page to edit a password?

Tags: password, security, edit

I was wondering about changing a password in an application. Is it more correct to ask as usual, all three (old, new and confirm) passwords on the same page or is it better to ask for the old password on the first page beforehand? Once prior one verified, asking for the new and confirmation passwords on second page.

The aim is to make users focus on only one form at a time so that, making recognition more easier and immediate. I was wondering whether it's more or less convenient in terms of specific reasons and is there any security problems for each pattern.

[image]

Comment: One slight advantage to more than one page is that browsers will have an easier time realizing which is the new password -- as long as you're sure to also restate the username on the second page.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are only 3 inputs, I don't see a cognitive load problem with a single-page solution.

What kind of security issues do you have in mind? I don't think if you split this into two sections you'd have to store the old password in a cache or anything like that. It has to pass a check anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure. Was thinking at something like a bigger vulnerability at bruteforce attacks or something like this considering that there is only a field and has a directly request. I also don't think that in this specific phase there are limitations on attempts like during the login.